# MS FILETIME as Absolute Time Stamp for Data Logging seems to be a good option

Tags: logging, timestamp, absolute, filetime

FILETIME as Absolute Time Stamp for Data Logging seems to be a good option,

someone knows how to make FILETIME work on Raspberry Pi ?

FILETIME counts the number of hectonano-seconds (0.1 us units) since Jan 1, 1601.

Raspberry Pi has a 64-bit micro-second counter (Pi_Counter) that starts counting while the unit is powered on, as far as I understand.
Raspberry Pi also has a Pi_Clock that is initialized with NTP, if enabled and available, and/or a battery driven Real-Time Clock.
Given this, looks like we can produce FILETIME on the Raspberry Pi the following way:

FILETIME= Pi_Counter*10 + Actual_Init_Constant;
Where the Actual_Init_Constant is calculated as sum and differences between  (Jan 1, 1601), Pi_Clock (actual time) and (Pi_Counter) all converted to hectonano-seconds (0.1 us units).

Some one knows how to make it work?